# Set AccessibleName For CEdit Control

Tags: c++, mfc, accessibility

How to set accesible name for CEdit control in MFC windows to be read by screen reader program such as Jaws and NVDA.

Any helps would be very appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18290/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Active-Accessibility) helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't tel about MFC but only for win32.

Comment: MFC is a (thin) wrapper around the Windows API. *Any* solution using the Windows API is equally applicable to MFC.

Comment: See `get_accName` on [Edit Control (MSAA UI Element Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318062(v=vs.85).aspx)